# export C data structures to a Grafana-supported database: your advice?

Tags: c, database, postgresql, structure, grafana

I have a C program which fills and calculates the data structures like

```
struct Users
{
    unsigned char login[LOGIN_SIZE+1];
    unsigned int hours, minut, works;
    struct Range {
        unsigned int hours_a, minut_a, time_a;
        unsigned int hours_b, minut_b, time_b;
        unsigned int dur_hours, dur_minut, dur_time;
        struct WorkIDs {
            unsigned int work_id;
            unsigned int filled;
        } work;
        unsigned int filled;
    } range[RANGE_SIZE];
    unsigned int verbosity;
    unsigned int filled;
} users[USERS_SIZE];
```

Now I need to export the filled data structures from C program to any of the Grafana-supported databases, i.e.: **InfluxDB**, **MySQL** or **PostgreSQL** *(full list is available at https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/ and may be expanded with plugins)*

However, I couldn't find any good example of exporting a C filled data structure to a database, and struggle establishing a connection between these technologies. Please could you advise a right approach?

Comment: Make JSON doc from your structure and insert it to the storage with JSON doc support, e.g. Elasticsearch, PostgreSQL, ... Of course keep in mind how do you want to select data from that JSON doc, because that can be another limitation, which will change range of suitable storages for your use case.

Comment: @JanGaraj Thank you. So far I find the stuff like JSON-C but it seems to parse a C source to generate JSON which isn't filled with any data. Do you know any C example of exporting a struct to JSON, which can be injected to C program's code?

Answer (score 0):

**My working approach *(feel free to suggest the alternatives!)***

**1) use a PostgreSQL** : unlike MySQL which gave me a lot of various errors until I gave up, the installation of PostgreSQL was really quick and straightforward, just follow an article like https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-18-04 to quickly get started with your first example database.

**2) take a libpqxx library** : they give a great C++ example at documentation http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/ , which could be built with a command like `c++ -o post post.cxx -lpqxx -lpq`. Your `libpqxx` library needs to be above a certain version for this example to work! On a Linux Mint 19.3, I had to download `libpqxx-6.2_6.2.5-1_amd64.deb` and `libpqxx-dev_6.2.5-1_amd64.deb` of "The Eoan Ermine" from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libpqxx : because building a fresh `libpqxx` from source isn't that easy, while its' version at Linux Mint distro's official repositories is way too old and not sufficient.

Connection string at this C++ example could be replaced with something like
`pqxx::connection c("dbname=anonymous host=localhost user=anonymous password=123");` and then it works. Whole modified source code, to match a tutorial from 1 - paint all the playgrounds to a color of your choice:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

int main(int, char *argv[])
{
  pqxx::connection c("dbname=anonymous host=localhost user=anonymous password=123");
  pqxx::work txn(c);
  int equip_id = 1;
  std::cout << "Updating equip_id #" << equip_id << " and others" << std::endl;

  for (equip_id = 1; equip_id < 3; equip_id++) {
      txn.exec0(
        "UPDATE playground "
        "SET color = " + txn.quote(argv[1]) +
        "WHERE equip_id = " + txn.quote(equip_id));
  }
  // Make our change definite.
  txn.commit();
}
```

Then, it's just a matter of time before you could export the C structure data fields into this PostgreSQL database using lots of SQL queries in a cycle; although, you'd also need to come up with a good database structure and add it to PostgreSQL using a `psql` interactive command line before doing this.

**3) Install Grafana and configure PostgreSQL data source** - using the tutorials like

- https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/debian/
- https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/getting-started/getting-started/
- https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/postgres/

I had to disable a SSL mode at `Data Sources / PostgreSQL` configuration to successfully connect to a database using the same username/password as your C++ program *(didn't need to specify a port)*.